# IOS go to specific view from tabbar controller from other view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view with 3 buttons and a tabbar controller that contains 3 views. I am using the storyboard. I want go from my view to a specific view from the tabbar controller. When I create a segway to the destination view, the tabbar is not included.

The only way I find out is to create a segway to the tabbar controller itself, but then by default the first view is been shown.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yess!! I got the solution. Do the following:

**In you're .h file:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabController;
```

**In you're .m file:**

```
@synthesize tabController;

tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
```

The selected index is the tab you want to go

```
tabController.selectedIndex = 1;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```